# Error downloading net.cakesolutions:scala-kafka-client - Not Found

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, sbt

I'm trying to install Kafka in my sbt, but when I click on "import changes" I'm getting an error:

> [error] stack trace is suppressed; run 'last update' for the full
>   output [error] stack trace is suppressed; run 'last
>   ssExtractDependencies' for the full output [error] (update)
>   sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: Error downloading
>   net.cakesolutions:scala-kafka-client_2.13:2.3.1 [error]   Not found
>   [error]   Not found [error]   not found:
>   C:\Users\macca.ivy2\local\net.cakesolutions\scala-kafka-client_2.13\2.3.1\ivys\ivy.xml
>   [error]   not found:
>   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/cakesolutions/scala-kafka-client_2.13/2.3.1/scala-kafka-client_2.13-2.3.1.pom
>   [error] (ssExtractDependencies)
>   sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: Error downloading
>   net.cakesolutions:scala-kafka-client_2.13:2.3.1 [error]   Not found
>   [error]   Not found [error]   not found:
>   C:\Users\macca.ivy2\local\net.cakesolutions\scala-kafka-client_2.13\2.3.1\ivys\ivy.xml
>   [error]   not found:
>   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/cakesolutions/scala-kafka-client_2.13/2.3.1/scala-kafka-client_2.13-2.3.1.pom
>   [error] Total time: 1 s, completed 19:56:34 26/04/2020 [info] shutting
>   down sbt server

build.sbt:

```
name := "KafkaProducer"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.13.0"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "io.circe" %% "circe-parser" % "0.12.3",
  "net.cakesolutions" %% "scala-kafka-client" % "2.3.1"
)
```

Comment: Sure, `https://repo1.maven.org` wouldn't be found, but the logs should also now include `bintray`. However, why do you need this? `kafka-streams` already includes Scala clients since verison 2.0. And `org.apache.kafka % kafka-clients % 2.0` works fine with Scala

Comment: @cricket_007 with this dependency I'm still getting the exact same error.

Comment: Are you behind a proxy? This works fine for me https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.kafka/kafka-streams/2.5.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of today Scala is still not binary compatible between versions and has tendency to serious breaking changes between "minor" (2.10 -> 2.11 -> 2.12 -> 2.13) releases.

It leads to situation where maintainers are relatively slow in adopting new versions.

e.g. Apache Spark barely started supporting 2.12 in the last stable version.

And even to the point where it is a default one.

So if I want to run this with 2.13 I have three options:

1. sbt publish-local
2. Using [standard Java client](https://docs.confluent.io/current/clients/java.html#java-client) instead
3. Nagging maintainer of Scala package to publish artificats

But I've decided to solve it by just downgrading Scala to 2.12

Answer (score 2):

Per the [github page for `scala-kafka-client`](https://github.com/cakesolutions/scala-kafka-client), you'll need to add a bintray resolver to your build.sbt:

```
resolvers += Resolver.bintrayRepo("cakesolutions", "maven")
```

Comment: @Alon You should get a different error if you added a repo to the resolvers

Comment: @cricket_007 I swear it's the same one